# Wildcard Certificate Setup

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, ssl-certificate-errors

We recently had a project pushed through that I didn't have time to research first.  We were asked to set up a site and purchased a wildcard certificate from GoDaddy.  The instructions for most of the certificate requests and installs are for apache, iis, etc.  I was told by their support to make the request from the domain name server, so I did it from the DC that holds the FSMO roles.  Now I can download the wildcard cert but I only see instructions on how to implement it through iis services, which is a role our DC doesn't have.

I was told by my senior to add the cert to our gpo to install it district-wide.  What confuses me is that based on GoDaddy's instructions, since they offer an intermediate cert accompanied, don't I have to have the intermediate cert somewhere publicly available to then receive the primary certificate, or is that essentially what I accomplished when I set up the initial request to download the certificate?

I thought that the proliferation of the wildcard certificate would mean that I would no longer see errors while attempting to browse to anny iis-hosted site ie. computername.fqdn.com.  This was initially done to use Federation Services tied in through a proxy which isn't working.  There are many moving parts to that but I feel like the certificate isn't set up properly, which is my first inclination as to why it could not be working.

Obviously my understanding of certs is fairly limited so I hope I've made this clear as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can distribute the certificate using GPO.
What I'm sure is that you have a private key for the certificate (so the certificate in the bottom right corner has a little yellow key) in his icon.

If so you can use MMC/certificates and search on the local computer and in the local user stores. you should find it in the local computer storage and in there you can export it to a PSF file with a password that you can easily just go thru servers and right click install ...

Answer (score 0):

The intermediate cert will need to be available during the SSL handshake to authenticate properly. What do you get if you go to https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html and put in the domain name where the cert is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Below, two resources from GoDaddy will give you detailed information and help you step by step for where you are missing the process.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/download-my-ssl-certificate-files-4754
https://www.godaddy.com/help/ssl-certificates-1000006